# How can I apply scripts in new camera which is child of a gameobject

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

Earlier I was facing problem regarding the unity camera problem it always stuck on 0,0,0.08 and also find a solution so I first create an empty gameobject and then drag the camera in that empty gameobject but after doing this the scripts which I applied to the gameobject is working fine but the script which I place in camera is not working at all

Camera Script

```
public float MovementAmplitude = 0.1f;
public float MovementFrequency = 2.25f;
void Update()
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(
         transform.position.x,
         Mathf.Cos(transform.position.z * MovementFrequency) * MovementAmplitude,
         transform.position.z

        );
}
```

Player Script

```
public float speed = 4.5f;
public float JumpingForcec = 450f;
void Update()
{
    transform.position += speed * Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime;
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
        Debug.Log("SPace is pressed");
        Debug.Log(GetComponent<Rigidbody>());
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up * JumpingForcec);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear: as I understand you attach the camera script to the Camera, and the player script to another object e.g. player. And the camera object is a child of the player object right?

Comment: yes, you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all when dealing with a `Rigidbody` (or the Physics in general) you shouldn't set a position directly through the `Transform` component but rather use [`Rigidbody.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-position.html) or in your case for a smooth movement even rather [`Rigidbody.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html), both in [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html).

In general anything related to the Physics (so also everything using `Rigidbody`) should be done in `FixedUpdate` while the check for `GetKeyDown` has to be done in `Update`.

PlayerScript

```
public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 4.5f;
    public float JumpingForcec = 450f;

    // If possible reference this in the Inspector already
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody rigidBody;

    private bool jumpWasPressed;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!rigidBody) rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rigidBody.MovePosition(transform.position + speed * Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);

        if (!jumpWasPressed) return;

        Debug.Log("SPace was pressed");

        rigidBody.AddForce(Vector3.up * JumpingForcec);

        jumpWasPressed = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Note that currently you can multijump .. later you will want to add 
        // an additional check if you already jump again
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) jumpWasPressed = true;
    }
}
```

**Make sure that [`Is Kinematic`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html) is *disabled* in the `Rigidbody` component! Otherwise `AddForce` is not processed.**

> If `isKinematic` is *enabled*, Forces, collisions or joints will not affect the rigidbody anymore.

The camera movement I would move to [`LateUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html) in order to make sure it is the last thing calculated after the other `Update` calls have finished. Especially after all user input has been processed (in your case maybe not that relevant since movement is processed in `FixedUpdate` but in general).

Second problem: Here you are not taking the changed Y position by jumping into account so rather add the "wobbling" effect to the player's `transform.position.y` and rather use the localPosition for the Camera:

```
public class CameraScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float MovementAmplitude = 0.1f;
    public float MovementFrequency = 2.25f;

    // reference the player object here
    public Transform playerTransform;

    private float originalLocalPosY;

    private void Start()
    {
        if(!playerTransform) playerTransform = transform.parent;
        originalLocalPosY = transform.localPosition.y;
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        transform.localPosition = Vector3.up * (originalLocalPosY + Mathf.Cos(playerTransform.position.z * MovementFrequency) * MovementAmplitude);
    }
}
```

---

Maybe you want to disable the wobbling effect during a jump later, though ;)

[image]

Comment: Still not working. the Player is moving in z-position and camera is only waving in y as we did in LateUpdate not jumping when I hit space. `Debug.Log("SPace was pressed");` also showing space when we hit space

Answer (score 0):

Try to put all the update stuff in the same method, it should work both (theorically, not tested) so you have to fix your code in order to get what you want:

```
void Update() {
    // Camera update
    transform.position = new Vector3(
        transform.position.x,
        Mathf.Cos(transform.position.z * MovementFrequency) * MovementAmplitude,
        transform.position.z
    );
    // Player update
    transform.position += speed * Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime;
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
        Debug.Log("SPace is pressed");
        Debug.Log(GetComponent<Rigidbody>());
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up * JumpingForcec);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you, cheers!

Comment: yeah, I also try this approach but in that case ` GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up * JumpingForcec);` is not working. In `  Debug.Log(GetComponent<Rigidbody>());` the output at the console is Player but it is not jumping that's why I separate the scripts

Comment: do you test the current value of every 3D coord float in the Vector3 constructor? im pretty sure that's the camera problem, it might be the math operation inside the parentesis. Be sure that is "Vector3(float x, float y, float z)" before construct.

Comment: @sebastianlopez by mixing both scripts you are now moving the wrong object .. the camera script is attached to another (child) GameObject so you can't use `transform` but have to use the `Transform` component of the camera on instead... e.g. `GetComponentInChildren<Camera>(true).transform` (you shouldn't use this in `Update` but rather store and reuse it!)